# sort random list of numbers into groups based on range

Tags: python, list, sorting

Thanks in advance for any advice!
I have a random group of numbers that need to be sorted into groups based on their range... I could use some advice how to do this...thanks in advance

So, I imagine the code works like this:
Take a list of 100 random numbers ranging from 0-1000
Split the range (from 0-1000) into x number of groups (say 10 groups: 0-100,100-200, 200-300 etc...)
For i in this list
test if its in group 1
if true add this to a list
if not test consecutive groups

the thing is the  number of groups should be a variable that can be adjusted and the subsequent lists should be updated accordingly to the division of the range...

```
import random as r
#create list of random integers
ranInteger = []

#length of list of random integers
for i in range (10):
    ranInt = r.randint(0,1000)
    ranInteger.append(ranInt)
print "ranInteger =", ranInteger

#find bounds of random list of integers
maxL = max(ranInteger)
minL = min(ranInteger)
print "maxL =", maxL
print "minL =", minL  

#find range of random list of integers
rangeL = maxL - minL
print "rangeL =", rangeL 

#divide range to create grouping value
divRange = 10
grpValue = (rangeL / divRange)
print "grpValue =", grpValue 

#make List of grouping values
grpL =[] 
r2 = range (minL, maxL, int (grpValue))
grpL.append (r2)
print "grpL =", grpL

#tests each number
indexl = []
for j in ranInteger:
    #test each range
    if i >= ranInteger[s] and i< ranInteger [s+1]) or (s==0)):
print indexl
#to be honest I have no idea how to sort this list into different groups
#and to have the lists with groups update if the group division is changed 
#how can I dynamically create lists based on the value of other objects?
#so i can say divRange = 10 make 10 lists with values grouped in there 
#but if the user changes this divRange = 20 then it automatically makes 20 
#lists with new groups contained within
# I would also like these same lists but with the index of the grouped items
```

instead of the actual number

thank you!!! - E

Comment: I feel this is a bit underspecified. Can you give example input/output? Are the groups based on the *range*, i.e. `0-1000` or on the actual values? i.e., if we pick 10 random numbers in the range 0-1000, then we might get something like `[410, 465, 344, 221, 433, 260, 268, 108, 61, 583]`, where min/max is `(61, 583)`, in whichc ase, would we make the 10 groups based on that?

Comment: As an aside, your for-loop to generate `N` random numbers in a range could be replaced with `random.sample(range(start, stop + 1),  N)` assuming you want to select integers in the *inclusive* range `[start, stop]`

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to solve this type of problem is to write a function that does the work, and call that function with different input parameters.  Like this:

```
def make_bins(x_in, n_bins):  
    """
    x_in is a list of numbers
    n_bins is how many bins to separate x into
    returns a list of length of n_bins, each element of which is a list
    """
    x_min = min(x_in)
    x_max = max(x_in)
    x = [[] for _ in range(n_bins)]
    for a in x_in:
        # compute the bin number for value a
        n = int(float(a - x_min) / (x_max - x_min + 1.0) * n_bins)
        x[n].append(a)
    return x  # x is a binned list of elements from x_in
```

I've glossed over certain possible problems, like roundoff when defining the bin boundaries.  But it will work with lists of any length, and the items in the list don't have to be integers.

Comment: Thank you all for this helpful feedback!